# Safari favorites disappeared on my iMac

Tags: macos, safari

I have an iMac running High Sierra and Safari version 12.1.2. I have saved a selection of sites to Favorites. There were about 60 sites in the group. Just now something changed and when I select 'show favorites' the window has only 12 sites showing.  Where have all my favorites gone?

I've quit safari and restarted. I've restarted my computer. Neither worked.

Comment: Were they also synced via iCloud? If so, do they still appear on your other devices? And, dare I ask, do you have a Time Machine (or other) backup?

Comment: I think my sites were synced to iCloud but I can't be sure. I tried Safari on my iPad Pro but it has a different set of Favorites.  Time machine quit working about three weeks ago but I have backups before that. I also have Carbon Copy Cloner and Backblaze.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you where all your favourites have gone, but since you have a Time Machine backup from three weeks ago, your best bet is probably to recover them from there (as I'm guessing you haven't added a lot to your bookmarks in the past three weeks).

The file you're needing to replace is your **Bookmarks.plist** file. This is located in your user's Library folder. The full path is typically: `Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨username ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Safari⁩ ▸ Bookmarks.plist`

If your user's Library folder isn't visible, follow these steps to open it:

1. Go to Finder
2. Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while you click on the Go menu
3. Select Library
4. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now
5. Within the Library folder open the Safari folder
6. Now you'll see the **Bookmarks.plist** file that you need to recover from your Time Machine backup

---

Since following the above steps has resulted in the same outcome, it's time to check whether some of your Safari settings have changed. To do this:

1. Go to Safari > Preferences...
2. Make sure you're on the General tab (first icon along top)
3. Now check the options for each of the following settings:

   - Favorites Shows:
   - Top Sites Shows:
4. Exit Preferences
5. Now click on the Bookmarks menu
6. Double check that the Show Frequently Visited in Favorites option (second from top) is ticked

Now test again to see if this returns the previous behaviour?

Comment: @Monomeeth.Thanks for your answer.  I found an older Bookmarks.plist file from 2 of my backups. I renamed the original and copied one of these into the correct folder. When i restarted Safari all my bookmarks were there but it was same 12 only that were in Favorites.  I tried both files but no luck.  Any more suggestions? So it seems bookmarks.plist has my bookmarks saved but not necessarily the structure. Or maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I've added to my answer - let me know how you go.

Comment: Just following up on how you went with this? Did you get it sorted in the end?